# Ayuda con un código en HTML y JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

saben me podrían dar una sugerencia de como hacer la validación del siguiente código en html que tengo:

```
<select name="customer" id="customer">

<option>Seleccionar</option>
<option id="op1" value="General">General</option>
<option id="op2" value="Adulto Mayor">Adulto Mayor</option>
<option id="op3" value="Discapacitado">Discapacitado</option>
<option id="op4" value="Estudiante">Estudiante</option>
<option id="op5" value="Convenios">Convenios</option>
</select>
```

Además les dejo el código de la función en JavaScript que contiene los parámetros de validación para determinar ciertos comportamientos:

```
function ValidarCobroUsuario() 
{

var TipoCliente = document.getElementById('customer').value;

if (TipoCliente == 'General') 
{

    document.getElementById('pasaje1').value = '$450';

    var ExtraerMonto = document.getElementById('monto').value;

    var AplicarDescuento = ExtraerMonto - 450;


    document.getElementById('Tlt_Saldo').value = AplicarDescuento;  

    }
}
```

Bueno resulta que quiero tomar el valor del **select** *(Para el caso he programado solamente si se selecciona el valor **General**)*; y extraer el  valor del saldo de la tarjeta del cliente, ingresado por teclado, desde un **input** el cual.

Si el cliente es del tipo cliente **General** sobre el monto de la tarjeta no se realiza ningún descuento y se le resta el valor normal del pasaje (450) tal y como lo indica la función. *(Cabe mencionar además, que donde dice **pasaje1** en la función está estableciendo el valor de 450 al campo de texto correspondiente)*; como decía eso es lo que quiero lograr pero no me resulta y no me inserta los valores correspondientes a las respectivas cajas de texto que establecí. Alguna sugerencia, donde me equivoqué, que debo mantener o cambiar, si me pudieran ayudar, estaría muy agradecido.

Nota: Les dejo los **input** correspondientes a las cajas de texto en donde quiero ingresar los resultados.

**input del ingreso del monto de la tarjeta:**

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return SoloNumeros(event);" name="saldo" 
maxlength="8" placeholder="Ejemplo: 20000" id="monto"/>
```

**input del registro del cobro del pasaje:**

```
<label>VALOR PASAJE:</label>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="pasaje1" readonly=""/>
```

**input en donde se registra el resultado del descuento del Saldo por el valor del pasaje:**

```
<label>MONTO FINAL</label>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="Tlt_Saldo" readonly="" id="Tlt_Saldo">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas amigo espero esto sea lo que necesitas

La idea es obtener el valor que el cliente agrega en el `input` y el que selecciona en el `select` y hacer un `switch` con cada una de las opciones y poner el valor del pasaje en el `input` `#pasaje1` y al input total la resta de lo que agrego el usuario menos lo que vale el pasaje.

> NOTA: Para el ejemplo se uso unos valores al azar y la librería de javascript **jquery**.

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
$("#customer").change(function(){
  valor = $("#monto").val()
  cliente = $(this).val()
  
  switch (cliente) {
  case "General":
    console.log("general")
    $("#pasaje1").val("450")
    $("#Tlt_Saldo").val(valor - $("#pasaje1").val())
    break;
  case "Adulto Mayor":
    console.log("Adulto Mayor")
    $("#pasaje1").val("200")
    $("#Tlt_Saldo").val(valor - $("#pasaje1").val())
    break;
  case "Discapacitado":
    console.log("Discapacitado")
    $("#pasaje1").val("100")
    $("#Tlt_Saldo").val(valor - $("#pasaje1").val())
    break;
  case "Estudiante":
    console.log("Estudiante")
    $("#pasaje1").val("150")
    $("#Tlt_Saldo").val(valor - $("#pasaje1").val())
    break;
  case "Convenios":
    console.log("Convenios")
    $("#pasaje1").val("50")
    $("#Tlt_Saldo").val(valor - $("#pasaje1").val())
    break;
  default:
    
}
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number"  name="saldo" 
maxlength="8" placeholder="Ejemplo: 20000" id="monto"/> 
<select name="customer" id="customer">

<option>Seleccionar</option>
<option id="op1" value="General">General</option>
<option id="op2" value="Adulto Mayor">Adulto Mayor</option>
<option id="op3" value="Discapacitado">Discapacitado</option>
<option id="op4" value="Estudiante">Estudiante</option>
<option id="op5" value="Convenios">Convenios</option>

</select>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<label>VALOR PASAJE:</label>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="pasaje1" readonly=""/>
<br/>
<label>MONTO FINAL</label>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="Tlt_Saldo" readonly="" id="Tlt_Saldo">
```

Comment: Hola, me gustó tu respuesta pero ¿porque pusiste de igual manera la función que yo hice?, además estaba incompleta, o será que no la debo poner. Y por otro lado, el **switch()** funciona en base a un botón que se programa, pero mi idea era que esos valores para el pasaje y el descuento final del saldo de la tarjeta, se ingresen solo por haber seleccionado el tipo de cliente y previamente, además, haber ingresado una cantidad como saldo.

Comment: Buenas acomode la respuesta espero sea lo que buscas cualquier cambio que necesites o duda comunicamelo

Comment: Aah vale gracias